# How to match a Variable in a regexp?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a Tcl script in which I need to match a variable in a regular expression.
For instance, file has some lines of code containing 'major'. Out of all these lines I need to identify one particular line:

```
major("major",0x32)
```

I m using variable p1 for 'major' (`set p1 major`)

How can I write a regexp using variable p1 (`$p1`) to capture that particular line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regexp -- "$p1\\(\"$p1\",0x32\\)" $line match
```

In tclsh:

```
% set line {major("major",0x32)}
major("major",0x32)
% set p1 major
major
% regexp -- "$p1\\(\"$p1\",0x32\\)" $line match
1
% puts $match
major("major",0x32)
```

Comment: Be aware that as the contents of the variable is embedded into the regex pattern "as is", so unless you're in full control of the variable contents, it generally should be escaped as if the variable happens to contain any character special to the regexp syntax, it might interfere with the pattern in unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a String Match

If you just want to know whether a single line matches, you can test for `string match` rather than a regular expression. This is often faster and less finicky. For example:

```
set fh [open /tmp/foo]
set lines [read $fh]
close $fh

set p1 major

set lines [split $lines "\n"]
foreach line $lines {
    if {[string match *$p1* $line]} {set match $line}
}
puts $match
```

Note that this will store the entire line in *match*, and not just the search pattern. This is probably what you want, but your mileage may vary.